# How can I get simple Text from image?

Tags: tess4j

I have a image captcha

[image]

I already use Tess4j, but it cannot return perfect result.
I want to get text from simple image captcha same a picture. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Captchas are intentionally distorted and obscured to prevent computers from deciphering them.

Comment: How are you using tess4j? Do you do any preprocessing of the image?

Comment: @MatsLindh: Yes, I zoom+ images, but just 2/10 perfect result

Comment: Please add your current code and the result for the test image - that way any suggestion can be actually helpful with the library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Asprise OCR](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/ocr-api-for-java-csharp-vb.net.html). But I don't think any tool can give you a stable result in this task.